# How to read each line in a file backwards using Python

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to read a file (example below), line by line, backwards using Python.

```
abcd 23ad gh1 n d
gjds 23iu bsddfs ND31 NG
```

Note: I'm not trying to read the file from the end to the beginning, but I want to read each line starting from the end, i.e d for line 1, and NG for line 2.

I know that

```
with open (fileName) as f:
    for line in f:
```

reads each line from left to right, I want to read it from right to left.

Comment: So you're asking how to reverse a string, then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       for item in line.split()[::-1]:
           print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not too big, you can read lines in reverse easily

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
        # do something
```

Otherwise, I believe you'd have to use `seed`.